# Removing cut-off edge from linear-gradient grid pattern?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a grid pattern that I have created using a linear-gradient.

```
#grid {
    margin-left:80px; 
    margin-right:80px; 
    height:289px; 
    background-size: 48px 48px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, grey 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, grey 1px, transparent 1px);
}
```

The problem is that the right side of the grid cuts-off instead of showing the edge. [How it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT4nu.png)

How can I show the edge of the right side? Preferably, I would like to keep the margins the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `repeating-linear-gradient` instead and you will have a better control over the grid and you can make it responsive.

You will have a fixed number of row/column that will grow shrink depending the element size:

```css
.box {
  --nc:10; /* Number of columns */
  --nr:6; /* Number of rows    */
  width:80vw;
  margin:auto;
  height:60vh;
  border-top:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right ,transparent 0px calc(100%/var(--nc) - 1px),#000 calc(100%/var(--nc) - 1px) calc(100%/var(--nc))),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0px calc(100%/var(--nr) - 1px),#000 calc(100%/var(--nr) - 1px) calc(100%/var(--nr)));
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or you can keep the use of linear-gradient and consider the use of `round` as `background-repeat`. Resize the browser to see the effect:

```css
.box {
  width:80vw;
  margin:auto;
  height:80vh;
  border-top:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right ,transparent calc(100% - 1px),#000 calc(100% - 1px) 100%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent calc(100% - 1px),#000 calc(100% - 1px) 100%);
  background-size:40px 100%,100% 60px;
  background-repeat: round;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or `space`:

```css
.box {
  width:80vw;
  margin:auto;
  height:80vh;
  border-top:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right ,transparent calc(100% - 1px),#000 calc(100% - 1px) 100%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent calc(100% - 1px),#000 calc(100% - 1px) 100%);
  background-size:40px 100%,100% 60px;
  background-repeat: space;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

---

> space
>
> The image is repeated as often as will fit within the background positioning area without being clipped and then the images are spaced out to fill the area. The first and last images touch the edges of the area. If the background painting area is larger than the background positioning area, then the pattern repeats to fill the background painting area.

> round
>
> The image is repeated as often as will fit within the background positioning area. If it doesn’t fit a whole number of times, it is rescaled so that it does.

Reference: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#valdef-background-repeat-space

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a hack but see this (View Full page):

```css
#grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 289px; 
    background-size: 47.955555px 48px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, grey 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, grey 1px, transparent 1px);
}
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```

You will probably have to create media queries to control the width on smaller devices.

Comment: That's still cut off on the right side on my browser (Firefox 66 Mac)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your grid margin so it's centered automatically instead of an absolute margin width, then most importantly give it a width that is a multiple of 48px plus 1 px (otherwise when it adds 48px for the last square it might push it outside the right edge of whatever sizing or margins you've set):

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1681px;
```

For instance, 1680 pixels gives you 35 grid squares, but the right edge will disappear if you don't make it 1681.